# Why does my online SQL editor not understand group_concat_max_len?

Tags: sql, apache

I don't have extensive experience in sql but I know basic.

I use online sql executor to receive the json file which will be prodiced from [this](https://github.com/collab-uniba/Personality-Recognition-in-SD/blob/master/data/get_mail_corpus.sql) sql query.

```
SET group_concat_max_len=18446744073709547520;

SELECT 

CONCAT(

'[',

GROUP_CONCAT(

JSON_OBJECT(

'id',messages.message_id,

'mailing_list_url',messages.mailing_list_url,

'type_of_recipient',messages_people.type_of_recipient,

'email_address',messages_people.email_address,

'message_body',messages.message_body,

'is_response_of',messages.is_response_of

) SEPARATOR ',\r'),

']') AS list

FROM messages

LEFT JOIN messages_people

ON messages.message_id = messages_people.message_id

AND messages.mailing_list_url = messages_people.mailing_list_url

WHERE email_address IN ('dr@gorsvet.kz', 'mathews@uk2.net', 'd.jentsch@fu-berlin.de', 'atul.soman@microfocus.com', 'kkrugler_lists@transpac.com', 'hcorg@minions.org.pl', 'bruno.ronchetti@mac.com', 'christophe.thiebaud@sap.com', 'kc.baltz@copart.com', 'havanki4j@gmail.com', 'joseph.obernberger@ngc.com', 'goran@roseen.se', 'hboutemy@apache.org', 'johann@gyger.name', 'fredrik@jonson.org', 'jose-marcio.martins@mines-paristech.fr', 'dmytro.kostiuchenko@gmail.com', 'jochen.wiedmann@softwareag.com', 'guyskk@qq.com', 'alejandroscandroli@gmail.com', '1983-01-06@gmx.net', 'jstrayer@proofpoint.com', 'daniel@degu.cl', 'hontvari@flyordie.com', 'david@andl.org', 'gholmes@pinsightmedia.com', 'dennis.geurts@luminis.eu', 'carlspring@gmail.com', 'jozef.koval@protonmail.ch', 'gabriele.ctn@gmail.com', 'ashish.disawal@evivehealth.com', 'aarslan2@anadolu.edu.tr', 'kshukla@yahoo-inc.com', 'alex.huang@gmail.com', 'markus@openindex.io', 'marohn@sipgate.de', 'ea@apache.org', 'krzysztof.szalast@gmail.com', 'kfoskey@tpg.com.au', 'krauss@in.tum.de', 'kenhans@hotmail.co.uk', 'jokin.c@odeian.com', 'eitch@eitchnet.ch', 'm.kristian@web.de', 'bob.sandiford@sirsidynix.com', 'asandstrom2@eastlink.ca', 'kelly@apache.org', 'antony.blakey@linkuistics.com.au', 'ashawki@hotmail.com', 'h.klocker-mark@tsn.at');
```

However from the first line I receive error.

As instructions are not friendly for me please can you help me how could I take the final file?

Answer (score 1):

I had no clue that there are such things as online sql executors. Basically SQL injections as a service, nice.

Anyways, the command:

```sql
SET group_concat_max_len=18446744073709547520;
```

is not part of the official SQL standard and specific to the database server you are using (here MYSQL). From the [manual for `group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len):

> The maximum permitted result length in bytes for the GROUP_CONCAT() function. The default is 1024.

For this very reason a "online SQL executor" (wow, I am still puzzled) won't be able to run this. Anyways if you need this, you probably won't get around setting up a MYSQL server yourself. Or you could just use a [container](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

Comment: thank you. but their is not a database to run this query

Comment: You have to run this query against a mysql server. It contains very mysql specific commands. So if you don't have such a server you most likely need to set one up now.

Comment: I have wampserver and run it locally. I can't the first line to 1024 as it has problem with maxlength. After that I receive this error `Table 'mailcorpus.messages' doesn't exist` Can you run it successfully and receive results?

Comment: are you on a 32 or 64 bit platform?

Comment: 64 bit platform

Comment: ok look, your query runs on a table called `messages`. This tables has to exist in your database `mailcorpus`.  that's currently not the case you have to get that table from somewhere..

Comment: searching for `messages` on that repository yields only results in that query you posted. So there does not seem to be a database setup script provided in that repo. I would recommend to get in touch with the author of the code.